# Warning: Illegal string offset 'zerif_logo' wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, themes, wordpress-theming

I am working on `Wordpress V4.4.2` with the theme named `Zerif lite theme`. Everything working fine on local but on development server I am getting below error when updating any content by using `Customising` section.

> Warning: Illegal string offset 'zerif_logo' in
>   /wp-includes/theme.php on line 901

Code is

```
function get_theme_mod( $name, $default = false ) {
    $mods = get_theme_mods();

    if ( isset( $mods[$name] ) ) {
        /**
         * Filter the theme modification, or 'theme_mod', value.
         *
         * The dynamic portion of the hook name, `$name`, refers to
         * the key name of the modification array. For example,
         * 'header_textcolor', 'header_image', and so on depending
         * on the theme options.
         *
         * @since 2.2.0
         *
         * @param string $current_mod The value of the current theme modification.
         */
        return apply_filters( "theme_mod_{$name}", $mods[$name] );
    }

    if ( is_string( $default ) )
        $default = sprintf( $default, get_template_directory_uri(), get_stylesheet_directory_uri() );

    /** This filter is documented in wp-includes/theme.php */
    return apply_filters( "theme_mod_{$name}", $default );
}
```

line 901 code is

```
return apply_filters( "theme_mod_{$name}", $mods[$name] );
```

**EDIT**

After Placing

```
$mods = get_theme_mods();
var_dump('content of $mods', $mods);
```

I get below data

> string(16) "content of $mods" string(2208)
>   "h:22:{i:0;b:0;s:10:"zerif_logo";s:68:"http://example.in/clinic/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/Caduceus.svg_.png";s:11:"zerif_email";s:24:"support@myclinictest.com";s:13:"zerif_address";s:22:"Jaipur
>   Rajasthan
>   India";s:19:"zerif_bigtitle_show";s:0:"";s:30:"zerif_bigtitle_redbutton_label";s:7:"Contact";s:32:"zerif_bigtitle_greenbutton_label";s:11:"Appointment";s:20:"zerif_ourfocus_title";s:13:"Our
>   Specility";s:23:"zerif_ourfocus_subtitle";s:0:"";s:20:"zerif_bigtitle_title";s:24:"You
>   Deserve Right Doctor";s:22:"zerif_aboutus_subtitle";s:122:...... so on

How can I fix this error.

Comment: That message can only mean that `$mods` is a string, and not an array. But that is strange, because if it was a string, then `isset( $mods[$name] )` above should not be true in the first place … According to WP docs, `get_theme_mods` should return either an array, or false if no theme mods have been set. Put `var_dump('content of $mods', $mods);` after the first line of the function code, and see what result that gives. (Depending on where that function is called, the output might not visible on the page. In that case, search for `content of $mods` in the HTML source code.)

Comment: @CBroe : `string(16) "content of $mods" NULL` is the output

Comment: Did you place it after the `$mods = get_theme_mods();` line?

Comment: That looks like serialized data. No idea why the value _would_ be serialized at this point, that makes little sense – but if you are willing to modify that file, calling `unserialize($mods);` before the if statement could be an easy fix.

Comment: still same. `$mods = get_theme_mods(); unserialize($mods);$old_value = isset( $mods[ $name ] ) ? $mods[ $name ] : false;`

Comment: Well then it’s probably best if you ask the theme developer for support on this issue.

Comment: already posted. but no answer yet. Waiting.. :(